# Copula contour plot

Tags: r, statistics, copula

I am trying to get some nice contour plots of various Copulas with Gaussian marginals, but somehow I do not at all get what I would expect - what am I doing wrong ?

My R code:

```
library(copula)
library(mvtnorm)

#Gaussian Density & distribution
G_copula = norm.cop <- normalCopula(0.70)
cp <- contour(G_copula, dCopula, n=200, nlevels=20, delta=0.01)
persp(G_copula, dCopula)
contour(cp$x,cp$y,cp$z)
contour(qnorm(cp$x),qnorm(cp$y),cp$z)
```

What I would like to get is something like this
[image]

But what I get is this
[image]

Comment: The book Dependence Modeling with Copulas seems to suggest, in figure 1.2 that one should plot with contours

C( \phi(z_1), \phi(z_2)) \phi(z_1) \phi(z_2)

And shows the right figure, but it does not motivate it nor can I replicate the figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the contours plot of the copula with margins N(0,1) and N(0,1), one option is to "manually" define its density:

```r
library(copula)

cop <- normalCopula(0.7)

# density of the bivariate distribution with copula 'cop' and margins N(0,1), N(0,1)
f <- function(x, y) {
  dCopula(c(pnorm(x), pnorm(y)), cop) * dnorm(x) * dnorm(y)
}
```

Then you can use the usual `contour` function.

But it's easier to create this distribution with `mvdc`:

```r
library(copula)
mv <- mvdc(
  normalCopula(0.7), margins = c("norm", "norm"),
  paramMargins = list(list(mean = 0, sd = 1), list(mean = 0, sd = 1))
)
```

Then you can directly call `contour` on this multivariate distribution:

```
contour(mv, dMvdc, xlim = c(-3, 3), ylim = c(-3, 3), asp = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I needed!

For others reading - the key for me was that instead of using cp$z one should indeed use

dCopula(c(pnorm(x), pnorm(y)), cop) * dnorm(x) * dnorm(y)

corresponding to the (bivariate) density F_(X,Y) so it is exactly what was needed and is easily generalized to other marginals and copulas from the Copula package. See details on wikipedia for a derivation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you've provided, this plot you are trying to recreate just looks like the bivariate normal distribution, which is used to create your copula. You can create a contour plot of the bivariate normal distribution, matching the parameters you used for your copula, as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)

mu <- c(0, 0)
sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0.7, 0.7, 1), 2, 2) # Use a correlation of 0.7, matching your copula
bivariate_normal <- rmvnorm(100000, mean = mu, sigma = sigma)
colnames(bivariate_normal) <- c("x", "y")

df <- tibble::as_tibble(bivariate_normal)

df |>
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_density_2d() +
  labs(title = "Bivariate Normal Distribution (Correlation = 0.7)",
       x = "X", y = "Y")
```

The output looks like this: [image]